# changing podman build to path with more space

Tags: docker, image, containers, podman, docker-build

When running `podman build` I see this error:

```
error creating build container:
storing blob to file /var/tmp/storageXXX: no space left on device
```

I have another directory where I have a lot of space. How can I switch `podman build` to use the other directory?

Answer (score 1):

May podman answers will be similar to docker

## change docker images storage location

```bash
sudo sytemctl stop docker
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/docker /mnt/hd/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo ln -s /mnt/hd/docker /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by setting the TMPDIR directory to the intended target like this:

```
TMPDIR=/my/target/dir podman build --file Dockerfile
```

Comment: Probably the relevant documentation: https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/78f1ebb80ba473f4f9bb016aec5d190645089cce/docs/source/markdown/podman.1.md?plain=1#L158